# Livewire multi step form inside a bootstrap modal popup not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have followed this [guide](https://github.com/mberecall/Multi-Step-Form-Using-Laravel-Livewire)

The form is working, but when i try to put it inside a bootstrap modal, the next step button instead of moving to the next step, closing the modal popup. I don't understand how to fix this.
How to do this correctly i can't find information?

here is my code:

wizard.blade.php:

```
 <div>
    <div class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add_domain_popup"
    aria-hidden="true" style="top:10%" id="add_domain_popup">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="register">

                        {{-- STEP 1 --}}
               
                        @if ($currentStep == 1)
                            
                     
                        <div class="step-one">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">STEP 1/4 - Personal Details</div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="">First name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" wire:model="first_name">
                                               <span class="text-danger">@error('first_name'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                               <label for="">Last name</label>
                                               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last name" wire:model="last_name">
                                               <span class="text-danger">@error('last_name'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="">Gender</label>
                                                <select  class="form-control" wire:model="gender">
                                                       <option value="" selected>Choose gender</option>
                                                       <option value="male">Male</option>
                                                       <option value="female">Female</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="text-danger">@error('gender'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="">Age</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your age" wire:model="age">
                                                <span class="text-danger">@error('age'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Description</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" cols="2" rows="2" wire:model="description"></textarea>
                                        <span class="text-danger">@error('description'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
               
                        {{-- STEP 2 --}}
               
                        @if ($currentStep == 2)
                            
                       
                        <div class="step-two">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">STEP 2/4 - Address & Contacts</div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="">Email Address</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" wire:model="email">
                                                <span class="text-danger">@error('email'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                               <label for="">Phone</label>
                                               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter phone number" wire:model="phone">
                                               <span class="text-danger">@error('phone'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="">Country of residence</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" wire:model="country">
                                                    <option value="" selected>Select country</option>
                                                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                                                    <option value="India">India</option>
                                                    <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                                                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                                                    <option value="Phillipines">Phillipines</option>
                                                    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                                                    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="text-danger">@error('country'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="">City</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter city" wire:model="city">
                                                <span class="text-danger">@error('city'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               
                        @endif
                        {{-- STEP 3 --}}
               
                        @if ($currentStep == 3)
                            
                    
                        <div class="step-three">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">STEP 3/4 - Frameworks experience</div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur explicabo, impedit maxime possimus excepturi veniam ut error sit, molestias aliquam repellat eos porro? Sit ex voluptates nemo veritatis delectus quia?
                                    <div class="frameworks d-flex flex-column align-items-left mt-2">
                                        <label for="laravel">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="laravel" value="laravel" wire:model="frameworks"> Laravel
                                        </label>
                                        <label for="codeigniter">
                                           <input type="checkbox" id="codeigniter" value="codeigniter" wire:model="frameworks"> Codeigniter
                                       </label>
                                       <label for="vuejs">
                                           <input type="checkbox" id="vuejs" value="vuejs" wire:model="frameworks"> Vue Js
                                       </label>
                                       <label for="cakePHP">
                                           <input type="checkbox" id="cakePHP" value="cakePHP" wire:model="frameworks"> CakePHP
                                       </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="text-danger">@error('frameworks'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
               
                        {{-- STEP 4 --}}
                        @if ($currentStep == 4)
                            
                    
                        <div class="step-four">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">STEP 4/4 - Attachments</div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque delectus officia inventore id facere at aspernatur ad corrupti asperiores placeat, fugiat tempora soluta optio recusandae eligendi impedit ipsam ullam amet!
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cv">CV</label>
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" wire:model="cv">
                                        <span class="text-danger">@error('cv'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="terms" class="d-block">
                                            <input type="checkbox"  id="terms" wire:model="terms"> You must agree with our <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                                        </label>
                                        <span class="text-danger">@error('terms'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               
                        @endif
               
                        <div class="action-buttons d-flex justify-content-between bg-white pt-2 pb-2">
               
                           @if ($currentStep == 1)
                               <div></div>
                           @endif
               
                           @if ($currentStep == 2 || $currentStep == 3 || $currentStep == 4)
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-secondary" wire:click.prevent="decreaseStep()">Back</button>
                           @endif
                           
                           @if ($currentStep == 1 || $currentStep == 2 || $currentStep == 3)
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success" wire:click.prevent="increaseStep()">Next</button>
                           @endif
                           
                           @if ($currentStep == 4)
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Submit</button>
                           @endif
                               
                              
                        </div>
               
                    </form>


                
                </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

http/controllers/livewire/wizard.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use App\Models\Student;

class Wizard extends Component
{

        use WithFileUploads;
    
        public $first_name;
        public $last_name;
        public $gender;
        public $age;
        public $description;
        public $email;
        public $phone;
        public $country;
        public $city;
        public $frameworks = [];
        public $cv;
        public $terms;
    
        public $totalSteps = 4;
        public $currentStep = 1;
    
    
        public function mount(){
            $this->currentStep = 1;
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.wizard');
        }
    
        public function increaseStep(){
            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->validateData();
             $this->currentStep++;
             if($this->currentStep > $this->totalSteps){
                 $this->currentStep = $this->totalSteps;
             }
        }
    
        public function decreaseStep(){
            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->currentStep--;
            if($this->currentStep < 1){
                $this->currentStep = 1;
            }
        }
    
        public function validateData(){
    
            if($this->currentStep == 1){
                $this->validate([
                    'first_name'=>'required|string',
                    'last_name'=>'required|string',
                    'gender'=>'required',
                    'age'=>'required|digits:2'
                ]);
            }
            elseif($this->currentStep == 2){
                  $this->validate([
                     'email'=>'required|email|unique:students',
                     'phone'=>'required',
                     'country'=>'required',
                     'city'=>'required'
                  ]);
            }
            elseif($this->currentStep == 3){
                  $this->validate([
                      'frameworks'=>'required|array|min:2|max:3'
                  ]);
            }
        }
    
        public function register(){
              $this->resetErrorBag();
              if($this->currentStep == 4){
                  $this->validate([
                      'cv'=>'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf|max:1024',
                      'terms'=>'accepted'
                  ]);
              }
    
              $cv_name = 'CV_'.time().$this->cv->getClientOriginalName();
              $upload_cv = $this->cv->storeAs('students_cvs', $cv_name);
    
              if($upload_cv){
                  $values = array(
                      "first_name"=>$this->first_name,
                      "last_name"=>$this->last_name,
                      "gender"=>$this->gender,
                      "email"=>$this->email,
                      "phone"=>$this->phone,
                      "country"=>$this->country,
                      "city"=>$this->city,
                      "frameworks"=>json_encode($this->frameworks),
                      "description"=>$this->description,
                      "cv"=>$cv_name,
                  );
    
                  Student::insert($values);
                //   $this->reset();
                //   $this->currentStep = 1;
                $data = ['name'=>$this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name,'email'=>$this->email];
                return redirect()->route('registration.success', $data);
              }
        }
    }
```

Multi step form is working correctly, but once i put the multi step form inside a bootstrap modal popup, the next step behavior is wrong. when clickling the next step button, instead of moving to the next step, the modal fade out.

Comment: The code seems to be incomplete. Could you please put the full code.

Comment: @Coola I have edited it, sorry was missing only the bootstrap modal part. should i add the livewire component as well? Edit: i have added wizard.php as well

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap in it's javascrpit has defined behavior on button click in modals (closing modal). Overriding that functionality is not recommended. Instead you could try to trigger modal opening (same modal) again on any button by adding html tags like this:

```
<div class="action-buttons d-flex justify-content-between bg-white pt-2 pb-2">
       
@if ($currentStep == 1)
<div></div>
@endif
       
@if ($currentStep == 2 || $currentStep == 3 || $currentStep == 4)
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-secondary stepperButtonRegister" wire:click.prevent="decreaseStep()" onclick="stepperModalToggle()">Back</button>
@endif
                   
@if ($currentStep == 1 || $currentStep == 2 || $currentStep == 3)
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success stepperButtonRegister" wire:click.prevent="increaseStep()" onclick="stepperModalToggle()">Next</button>
@endif
                   
@if ($currentStep == 4)
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
@endif
                       
</div>
```

Note: data-target, data-toggle and data-dismiss attributes are used in Bootstrap 4, if you are using Bootstrap 5  those attributes should be data-bs-target, data-bs-toggle and data-bs-dismiss

Edit: added CSS class to next/back buttons (class name is stepperButtonRegister), removed modal toggle attributes from buttons (javascript should take that part over) and block below should show how script should look like (edit: would probably not work, replaced):

Edit2: replaced listener to in element listener as buttons would be loaded again with each step (former listener will not work with newly loaded buttons), and javacsript function should be:

```
function stepperModalToggle(){
    const myModalEl = document.getElementById('add_domain_popup');
    myModalEl.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', event=>{
        myModalEl.show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work for me.. I have added exactly(just with data-bs because i am using bt5), same happens when I click "next" the modal closing.

Comment: Edited answer to work with javascript event listener on buttons and modal elements, because probably it was trying to open same modal while transition (fading) wasn't over yet. Generally, best way would be to work with different modals for each step, even better with livewires modals, but it also complicates things (frankly, not even sure if possible, but you can find documentation at [link](https://github.com/wire-elements/modal )

Comment: appreciates your help, but this also did not work...